# Error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Gesture Control Video Player using OepnCV.py", line 51, in <module>
    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(500,700))
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.11) /tmp/pip-req-build-a3rwegmg/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3929: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what does the error message tell you? please present your own effort into solving the question.

Comment: Your frame input is either empty due to the frame reading or the path the video  recording is in error. Please show more code.

Answer (score 0):

This assertion error in OpenCV means that `frame` variable is empty. If you are displaying an image, this can be caused by the file path to the image being incorrect or the file being corrupted. If you are displaying a video input, you might have setup the frame capture from the camera incorrectly. There are other ways to getting this assertion error, but these are the most likely. Make sure that they aren't occurring in your code.

Comment: "an assertion error" doesn't mean that in general. always look at the asserted expression. in this case, we merely know that `frame` was empty, not why.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the comment! I updated my answer to include the fact that ```frame``` is empty, possibilities if video is being displayed, explaining there are other possibilities for assertion error, and telling OP to check that these possibilities are not present in their code.

Comment: to clarify, *this* assertion error, saying `(-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty()`, means that the variable was empty. "**an assertion error**", as you phrased it, does **not generally** mean that, but means whatever assertion accompanies it. I am not sure you understand my point but I can only repeat myself.

Comment: Understood. I have edited my answer to include that we are discussing this **specific** assertion error, not assertion errors in OpenCV as a whole.